# Can't run /usr/bin/demo from lua scripts

Tags: lua

lua version = 5.3.4.
I want to run os.excute`(/usr/bin/demo &)` in lua，it will occur  `attempt to call a nil value (field 'execute')`
But when I am in **Lua interactive mode**, it is normal to execute os.execute("/usr/bin/demo &").

1. Does the Lua script have no permission to execute shell instructions?
2. Or is there any other better way to execute shell instructions?

I need it running in lua scripts file

Comment: How do you run the script? Simple `lua execute.lua` (or another filename)? Do you by any chance change `os` at any point?

Comment: Some Lua environments (such as a game scripting environment) deliberately remove potentially dangerous functions from the Lua standard library, such as file access or command execution.

Comment: Yes, there is a sandbox limiting the standard lua api, thanks